# Error: could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth" observed while working authentication with Twitter

Tags: r, analytics, twitter-oauth

```
install.packages("twitteR")
install.packages("ROAuth")
install.packages("RCurl"")
install.packages("base64inc")
library(twitteR)
library(RCurl)
library(ROAuth)
api_key <- "xxxx"
api_secret <- "xxxx"
access_token <- "xxxxx-xxxx"
access_token_secret <- "xxxx"
```

> setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, credentials_file=NULL)
>   Error: could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth"
>
> twitteR:::setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
>   [1] "Using direct authentication"
>   myTweet <- searchTwitter("ipl", n=50)
>   Error: could not find function "searchTwitter"

These are the errors i am getting.
Please help.